# Cheapest USD to GBP transfer

Tags: foreign-exchange, money-transfer, international-transfer

I have recently returned from a year in the US and have my last month's paycheck sitting in my US bank account (which I have yet to close). I'd like to transfer most of it (say, $4500) into my UK bank account. What is the cheapest way to do this, bearing in mind that:

- Bank of America's own transfer service will only let me transfer $1000 at a time and will charge me $35 each time. And my UK bank will also charge.
- My US account is based in Massachusetts so I can't use transferwise
- I'm not desperate for the cash and don't mind doing something else with my dollars (stocks or some other investment) as long as I can ultimately convert to GBP at a decent rate and can do it legally without having an address in the US.

Comment: Related: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/37233/cheapest-way-to-wire-or-withdraw-money-from-us-account-while-living-in-europe/37258

Comment: And others. I think this is effectively a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Use a remitting service such as Ria Money Transfer. Almost all these services allow you to transfer upto $2999 at a time. So, you would be able to transfer the entire amount of $4500 within 2 business days(There is a monthly limit too, but it will definitely be more than $4500). There are no fees to use these services, but they do scrape off a bit on the currency rate. As of today you are getting 624 GBP for $1000 whereas the market rate is $641.95. You still save roughly $17 and 4 transactions, which adds up to more than $100. Here is a [link](https://www.riamoneytransfer.com/) to Ria's website. Other services, include Xoom, Western Union, Money Dart and Money Gram.